# Honeypot Anti-SPAM technique. How to randomly generate a name for the hidden field every site load?

Tags: php, mysql, session, captcha, honeypot

First, let me explain an anti-spam concept: Two months ago I faced a problem on my dad's company's website. It has a contact form but russian bots started to spam the server's mailbox quite often (three to five messages a day). I improved the captcha (more complicated font, different backgound, etc.) but that didn't seem to be a permanent solution. The bots were a little smarter than I expected. I started reading different anti-spam concepts and the found the "[honeypot method](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/)". It worked for a while, but the bots learned the name of the field the first week after implementation. Now, every morning I have to open the PHP files and think of a new name for that hidden field.

OK. To the question. I need to generate random names for that field, but I need a concept of how to do it. Right now I'm using a PHP script that does the following:

1: Deletes all recorded sessions in a MySQL DB, older than 10 mins.

2: Checks if a session is set for the current user.

3: If the session is set less than 10 mins ago, it just updates it, writing the current output of `time()` into the database.

4: If not - starts a new session and records it's `session_id()` in MySQL.

I have 4 columns in my MySQL table: id(PRIMARY KEY, the ID of the record); sess_id(Where I put the output of `session_id()` and use it for managing the users' sessions); session_started(contains the output of `time()`); tf_name(contains a randomly generated string which should be used later as a name attribute of the honeypot field).

In general, this concept works. But it limits the user to send a message no longer than 10 minutes after the page loaded. I need to eliminate the time factor.

One of the solutions, in my opinion, would be to generate a new PHP session on site load and to `session_destroy()` it when the user leaves the website (close the browser, click an external link, etc.) But this seems to be difficult to implement due to the fact, that I don't want to use JavaScript (therefore, can't use the onunload event) and the fact, that onunload event will fire no matter if you click an external link or internal link (or you submit a contact form, which will generate a new name for the honeypot field).

Comment: Couldn't you just increase the limit to - say - an hour? It should be pretty rare that someone wants to send you a message more than an hour after he last loaded any page...

Comment: Did you try a CAPTCHA? This might be the most simple solution to stop bot spam. If this is still to simple. You can look into creating a token(secret id) for each form. good explanation where i learned alot is here: https://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/

Comment: use reCAPTCHA, its very easy to implement https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: @Kempeth, I want to eliminate the time factor at all. Also, take me for example. If I open a page at 02:00 AM, and I have a question, I would leave it for the next day.

baboizk, read my question. I used a CAPTCHA, but the bots turned out to be smarter than I thought. I also, do not want to use external services. Checking the secret id link right now :)

Comment: Sorry, my response is so late! I've been researching the token technique because one of the things that went thru my mind before asking here was something relatively close to it (token). But I couldn't find an answer to another question: Are the bots requesting my form, or are they sending POST queries to the PHP script which sends the e-mails. I implemented the @baboizk 's way and now, I'm waiting to see if that will have any effect. Can anybody come up with an idea how to test it (or just to enlighten me how those tests are usually done)?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the concept know as csrf, or Cross-Site Request Forgery. I believe this will be a much more pragmatic solution than a roll-your-own solution in my opinion.

Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Exp: https://github.com/smiegles/PHP-csrf-security-classes

I see you are already using captcha but the bots where able to get around it; use a better captcha :). The two captcha's that I personally have had good luck with are the ones that require a simple math answer `(3+4)` or the `I am not a robot` checkbox.

Ref: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Ref: https://github.com/nettraction/Math_Captcha